# What ASP.NET components are there for implementing “secure messaging” within a web application?

Tags: asp.net, security, email, encryption, message

I’m talking about something like the “message inbox” that your bank or broker uses to communicate with you.

Not something for messaging between components, but pseudo-email or “private messaging” between users and/or between administrators and users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [SignalIR](http://signalr.net/)

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) for setting up a chat application

[Here is an article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/introduction-to-security) about security concerns in SignalIR

Comment: I want something for email specifically.

Comment: So why dont you just use email then?

Comment: This is for a medical product.  I can’t send the data over email, since email isn’t secure.  This is similar to the restrictions for banks.  You know like when your bank sends you an email that just says “login to the website to see a new message from us in your Message Center”?  I want a component that implements that Message Center.